# How to pop half a stack onto another stack

Tags: c++, arrays, string, stack, palindrome

Hey I'm working on a program using two stacks (created using array) to determine if a string is a palindrome.

I have declared two stacks. The plan is to read in the string, one by one, and push them onto the first stack.

Then, I will pop half the stack and push them onto the second stack. I can't figure out how to pop and push half the stack.

Comment: Can you post what you have done up till now? And highlight where you're having a problem?

Answer (score 0):

So given are two stack objects, which hold no value at first:

```
Stack stOne, stTwo;
```

Assuming that you have implemented `::size(), ::push(), ::pop()`, where pop returns the value stored on top of the stack, for your Stack objects, you want to push all chars of your given string into `stOne`. Then you will have to pop `stOne` for `stOne.size()/2` amount of times and push the chars into `stTwo`:

```
void solvePalindrome(std::string str){
    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++){
        stOne.push(str[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<stOne.size()/2; i++){
        stTwo.push(stOne.pop());
    }
    //do your comparison here
}
```

Alternatively, you can directly use str.size()/2 instead of stOne.size()/2 if you haven't implemented `::size()` yet.

Note: If you have an uneven amount of characters in your string, it will round down (floor) stOne.size()/2. All code is in CPP.

Comment: I'm getting an error at: " stOne.push(str[i]); ". I'm not sure how to post pictures on comments but, the the prototype for my push operation is void stack::push(item entry) so pushing "push(str[i])" wouldn't work.

Comment: You have to initialize the array as type char or use generic programming to allow it to have any primative type

Comment: `Stack stOne = new Stack();` will not compile in `C++`.

Comment: @Fureeish You are right, I got caught up with the Java constructor calling routine. To actually use the `new` keyword for creating an instance of `Stack`, you would need to change it to `Stack* stOne = new Stack();`. This would create the instance in dynamic memory, whilst with the updated `Stack stOne;` we are creating the instance in automatic storage.